# In Java, how can I print a blank line for every 5th row?

Tags: java, loops

It's basic programming but i'm still not entirely sure how to create a blank line every 5th row. Please help! Thank you!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("please enter an integer for the length");
    int theLength = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter an integer for the height");
    int theHeight = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter a character");
    String character1 = input.next();


    //  int character = Integer.toString(character1);

    for (int i = 0; i < theHeight; i++) {     //the outer loop controls the row


        for (int j = 0; j < theLength; j++) {// inner loop control 
            if (j % 6 != 0) { //creates a space for ever 5 character
                System.out.print(character1 + " ");
            } else System.out.print(" ");

        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: It isn't clear what you're asking here. Please provide expected vs. actual output, the exact issues you're having and a **clear** description of your problem.

Comment: It's not clear whether you're trying to create a space on every 5th row or every 6th row.

Comment: @Paula You may take a look at my solution.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you could change your `else` from a `print(" ")` to a `println`; like

```
if(j%6!=0){ //creates a space for ever 5 character
    System.out.print(character1 + " ");
} else {
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`println("...")` method prints the string and moves cursor to a new line, but The `print("...")` method instead prints just the string, but doesn't move cursor to a new line.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is zero based, so the row 0 is divisible by 5 too: if that meet your condition then modify the for loop as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < theHeight; i++) { // the outer loop controls the row
            for (int j = 0; j < theLength; j++) {// inner loop control
                if (i % 5 != 0) { // creates a space for ever 5 character
                    System.out.print(character1 + " ");
                } else {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }

            }
            System.out.println();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

> how can I print a blank line for every 5th row?

According to your codes, it seems to me you want to create a blank line after every ***n*** characters and not after ***n*** rows..

Be it you want to print a space or a newline after n rows or columns, you only need a single loop.

---

**Print a newline every 5 *characters:***

```
int height = 3, length = 5;
String myChar = "A";

for(int x=0; x<height * length; x++){
    System.out.print(myChar + " ");
    if( (x+1) % length == 0)  // (x+1) so the it won't print newline on first iteration
        System.out.println();
}
```

- `height * length` to get total number of characters to be printed
- `(x+1)`, because your x starts from `0`, and `0 % 0 = 0`.

**Output:**

```
A A A A A 
A A A A A 
A A A A A
```